# Display string[] array in a ListBox

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a wpf ListBox, i converted the DataSet to string[] array, and i'm trying to display the array in the listbox, but its not displaying.

This is my Code!!!

```
string query = " SELECT category_id, category_name, amount FROM acc_income_category WHERE deleted = 0 ORDER BY category_name ASC ";
da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(query, con);
ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "acc_income_category");
string[] arr = new string[ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    arr[i] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["category_name"].ToString();
}
ListBox_Category_Names.ItemsSource = arr;
```

And This is my WPF ListBox XAML Code

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox_Category_Names" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    Width="auto"  Height="auto" SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding acc_income_category}"  Grid.Row="1"  >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <CheckBox x:Name="chkBox_CheckCategory" Grid.Column="0" Width="35" Height="35" Cursor="Hand" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=IsSelected}"  />

                <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding category_name}" Grid.Column="1"  FontSize="15" Foreground="#FF666666" Margin="10,0,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding amount, ConverterCulture=ig-NG, StringFormat=\{0:C\}}" Grid.Column="3"  FontSize="15" Foreground="#FF666666" Margin="5,0,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>-->

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Why string array? Use binding, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363369/how-can-i-bind-a-listbox-to-a-data-table-in-wpf-applications

Comment: what happens if you just use the `.ToList()` to bind back to the ListBox 
`ListBox_Category_Names.ItemsSource = arr.ToList();` try googling on the following for some stackoverflow examples `C# stackoverflow Binding Listbox to List<object>` there are plenty of ways to do this

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480224.aspx

Comment: Thanks, But i'm trying to Convert the Dataset to Array, to store the whole column record in an array. and display the records as an array. How do i go about that.

Comment: And the main reason i'm using array, is because i have a button that will transfer a selected item from the list box the another lisbox. or is there any any other way i can go about that..

Answer (score 0):

Following piece of code works using Anugular-JS

```
var USState = ["Alabama", "Alaska" , "Arizona" ,"Arkansas", "California", 
        "Colorado", "Connecticut"];

$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
stateselect = document.getElementById("state");
for(i=0; i < USState.length; ++i) 
{
    var el=document.createElement('option');
    el.textContent = USState[i];
    stateselect.appendChild(el);
}
```

});